# PHP built in server, any way to configure it to show files of directory?

Tags: php

As yous may be aware, as of PHP 5.4 there is built in server available. However, if you browse to directory with no "index" file, instead if listing all available files/directories (like apache for example), it will give you and error.

Now as far as I understand this is by design and not some sort of bug. But maybe someone knows if there is a way to configure it, to list the contents of directory?

Comment: This isn't the purpose of the integrated web server. It is meant to be used for debugging purposes from a directory or input file. It's not meant to replace apache (or other web servers)

Comment: Agreed with @ColinMorelli ...but that said, it looks like someone's already implemented this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#110064

Comment: @MattBall I suppose you could call this "a way to configure it" :)

Comment: yeah, I do understand that. just for me personally it is easier to just type in directory name, and see all available files, rather than type in the file name as well. Just me being lazy :)

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned by Colin in his comment, the integrated server is intended for debugging purposes only, therefore you should expect it to not have all the features you would expect of a full server.

However, it's easy enough to build your own `index.php` to simulate the default Apache index:

```
<?php
$dir = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
echo "<h2>Index of ".$dir.":</h2>";
$g = glob("*");
usort($g,function($a,$b) {
    if(is_dir($a) == is_dir($b))
        return strnatcasecmp($a,$b);
    else
        return is_dir($a) ? -1 : 1;
});
echo implode("<br>",array_map(function($a) {return '<a href="'.$a.'">'.$a.'</a>';},$g));
```

Comment: +1 Second argument is missing though : `array_map(callback, $g)`.

Comment: +1 I have made a quick change which allows you to navigate through sub-folders: http://ideone.com/e01zat

Comment: Nice. But you should replace the second line with this line:

` echo "<h2>Index of ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].":</h2>";`

Comment: @Radon8472 Erm... no. Because I will not be responsible for `http://example.com/index.php/<script>alert('XSS!');</script>`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a closing `?>`?

Comment: Does a copy of this need to be in each subdirectory you want to navigate into? It seems like `href` should be `$dir/$a`.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but I feel this could still be useful.

I'm guilty of using the integrate web server not just for debug, but also to share files from random folders on my pc with virtualmachines or other pc in lan.

Said so, here's my updates script (it cam be used with "php -S localhost:8080 -t . script.php" from any folder):

```php
<style>
  a {
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  a:hover {
    background-color: #77AAFF;
    color: black;
  }

  .linkLeft {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }

  .linkCenter {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: -3px 10px 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  }

  .linkRight {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
</style>
<?php
$dir = realpath(isset($_GET['dir']) ? $_GET['dir'] : ".");
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  echo "<h2>Index of $dir:</h2>\n";
  $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
  usort($files, function($a, $b) use ($dir) {
    if (is_dir("{$dir}/{$a}") == is_dir("{$dir}/{$b}")) {
      return strnatcasecmp($a, $b);
    } else {
      return is_dir("{$dir}/{$a}") ? -1 : 1;
    }
  });
  echo "<a href='?dir=" . urlencode(realpath("{$dir}/..")) . "'>⏎</a>\n";
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_dir("{$dir}/{$file}")) {
      $typef = "[directory]";
    } else {
      $typef = "[" . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . " file]";
    }
    ?>
    <a href='?dir=<?= urlencode("{$dir}/{$file}"); ?>'>
      <div class='linkLeft'><?= $file; ?></div>
      <div class='linkCenter'></div>
      <div class='linkRight'><?= $typef; ?></div>
    </a>
    <?php
  }
} else if (is_file($dir)) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($dir) . '"');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir));
  readfile($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For show advanced list of files and directories with sort, date, size, icon type,..., Save bellow content code as `route.php` file, and then run this command:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t . route.php
```

And then open `http://localhost:8080/` in the browser.

Code:

```
<?php
//@NabiKAZ
//https://gist.github.com/NabiKAZ/91f716faa89aab747317fe09db694be8
//For show advanced list of files and directories with sort, date, size, icon type,...,
//Save bellow content code as route.php file, and then run this command:
//   php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t . route.php
//And then open http://localhost:8080/ in the browser.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This block MUST be at the very top of the page!
@ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
if(isset($_GET['icon']))
{
    $e=$_GET['icon'];
    $I['file']='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';
    $I['dir']='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';
    $I['doc']='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';
    $I['xls']='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';
    $I['jpg']=$I['gif']=$I['png']='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';
    $I['txt']='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';
    $I['avi']=$I['mpg']=$I['mpeg']=$I['mp3']='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';
    $I['pdf']='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';
    $I['rar']=$I['zip']='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';
    header('Cache-control: max-age=2592000');
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T',time()+2592000));
    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    print base64_decode(isset($I[$e])?$I[$e]:$I['file']);
    exit;
}
// End block

// Start configs
$sitename='My files';
$date='Y-m-d H:i:s'; // date format
$ignore=array('.','..','.htaccess','index.php','icon.php','Thumbs.db','web.config'); // ignore these files
// End configs
$root=dirname(__FILE__);
$dir=isset($_GET['dir'])?$_GET['dir']:'';if(strstr($dir,'..'))$dir='';
$path="$root/$dir/";
$dirs=$files=array();
if(!is_dir($path)||false==($h=opendir($path)))exit('Directory does not exist.');
while(false!==($f=readdir($h)))
{
    if(in_array($f,$ignore))continue;
    if(is_dir($path.$f))$dirs[]=array('name'=>$f,'date'=>filemtime($path.$f),'url'=>'index.php?dir='.rawurlencode(trim("$dir/$f",'/')));
    else$files[]=array('name'=>$f,'size'=>filesize($path.$f),'date'=>filemtime($path.$f),'url'=>trim("$dir/".rawurlencode($f),'/'));
}
closedir($h);
$current_dir_name = basename($dir);
$up_dir=dirname($dir);
$up_url=($up_dir!=''&&$up_dir!='.')?'index.php?dir='.rawurlencode($up_dir):'index.php';
// END PHP ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><?=$current_dir_name==''?'Directory list':$current_dir_name?></title>
<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial; font-size: 0.7em; color: black; padding-top: 8px; cursor: default; background-color: #fff; }
#idx { border: 3px solid #fff; width: 500px; }
#idx td.center { text-align: center; }
#idx td { border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0; }
#idx img { margin-bottom: -2px; }
#idx table { color: #606060; width: 100%; margin-top:3px; }
#idx span.link { color: #0066DF; cursor: pointer; }
#idx .rounded { padding: 10px 7px 10px 10px; -moz-border-radius:6px; }
#idx .gray { background-color:#fafafa;border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
#idx p { padding: 0px; margin: 0px;line-height:1.4em;}
#idx p.left { float:left;width:60%;padding:3px;color:#606060;}
#idx p.right {float:right;width:35%;text-align:right;color:#707070;padding:3px;}
#idx strong { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", tahoma, arial; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; color: #202020; padding-bottom: 3px; margin: 0px; }
#idx a:link    { color: #0066CC; }
#idx a:visited { color: #003366; }
#idx a:hover   { text-decoration: none; }
#idx a:active  { color: #9DCC00; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var _c1='#fefefe'; var _c2='#fafafa'; var _ppg=100; var _cpg=1; var _files=[]; var _dirs=[]; var _tpg=null; var _tsize=0; var _sort='date'; var _sdir={'type':0,'name':0,'size':0,'date':1}; var idx=null; var tbl=null;
function _obj(s){return document.getElementById(s);}
function _ge(n){n=n.substr(n.lastIndexOf('.')+1);return n.toLowerCase();}
function _nf(n,p){if(p>=0){var t=Math.pow(10,p);return Math.round(n*t)/t;}}
function _s(v,u){if(!u)u='B';if(v>1024&&u=='B')return _s(v/1024,'KB');if(v>1024&&u=='KB')return _s(v/1024,'MB');if(v>1024&&u=='MB')return _s(v/1024,'GB');return _nf(v,1)+'&nbsp;'+u;}
function _f(name,size,date,url,rdate){_files[_files.length]={'dir':0,'name':name,'size':size,'date':date,'type':_ge(name),'url':url,'rdate':rdate,'icon':'index.php?icon='+_ge(name)};_tsize+=size;}
function _d(name,date,url){_dirs[_dirs.length]={'dir':1,'name':name,'date':date,'url':url,'icon':'index.php?icon=dir'};}
function _np(){_cpg++;_tbl();}
function _pp(){_cpg--;_tbl();}
function _sa(l,r){return(l['size']==r['size'])?0:(l['size']>r['size']?1:-1);}
function _sb(l,r){return(l['type']==r['type'])?0:(l['type']>r['type']?1:-1);}
function _sc(l,r){return(l['rdate']==r['rdate'])?0:(l['rdate']>r['rdate']?1:-1);}
function _sd(l,r){var a=l['name'].toLowerCase();var b=r['name'].toLowerCase();return(a==b)?0:(a>b?1:-1);}
function _srt(c){switch(c){case'type':_sort='type';_files.sort(_sb);if(_sdir['type'])_files.reverse();break;case'name':_sort='name';_files.sort(_sd);if(_sdir['name'])_files.reverse();break;case'size':_sort='size';_files.sort(_sa);if(_sdir['size'])_files.reverse();break;case'date':_sort='date';_files.sort(_sc);if(_sdir['date'])_files.reverse();break;}_sdir[c]=!_sdir[c];_obj('sort_type').style.fontStyle=(c=='type'?'italic':'normal');_obj('sort_name').style.fontStyle=(c=='name'?'italic':'normal');_obj('sort_size').style.fontStyle=(c=='size'?'italic':'normal');_obj('sort_date').style.fontStyle=(c=='date'?'italic':'normal');_tbl();return false;}

function _head()
{
    if(!idx)return;
    _tpg=Math.ceil((_files.length+_dirs.length)/_ppg);
    idx.innerHTML='<div class="rounded gray" style="padding:5px 10px 5px 7px;color:#202020">' +
        '<p class="left">' +
            '<strong><?=$current_dir_name==''?$sitename:$current_dir_name?></strong><?=$dir!=''?'&nbsp; (<a href="'.$up_url.'">Back</a>)':''?><br />' + (_files.length+_dirs.length) + ' objects in this folder, ' + _s(_tsize) + ' total.' +
        '</p>' +
        '<p class="right">' +
            'Sort: <span class="link" onmousedown="return _srt(\'name\');" id="sort_name">Name</span>, <span class="link" onmousedown="return _srt(\'type\');" id="sort_type">Type</span>, <span class="link" onmousedown="return _srt(\'size\');" id="sort_size">Size</span>, <span class="link" onmousedown="return _srt(\'date\');" id="sort_date">Date</span>' +
        '</p>' +
        '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' +
    '</div><div id="idx_tbl"></div>';
    tbl=_obj('idx_tbl');
}

function _tbl()
{
    var _cnt=_dirs.concat(_files);if(!tbl)return;if(_cpg>_tpg){_cpg=_tpg;return;}else if(_cpg<1){_cpg=1;return;}var a=(_cpg-1)*_ppg;var b=_cpg*_ppg;var j=0;var html='';
    if(_tpg>1)html+='<p style="padding:5px 5px 0px 7px;color:#202020;text-align:right;"><span class="link" onmousedown="_pp();return false;">Previous</span> ('+_cpg+'/'+_tpg+') <span class="link" onmousedown="_np();return false;">Next</span></p>';
    html+='<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">';
    for(var i=a;i<b&&i<(_files.length+_dirs.length);++i)
    {
        var f=_cnt[i];var rc=j++&1?_c1:_c2;
        html+='<tr style="background-color:'+rc+'"><td><img src="'+f['icon']+'" alt="" /> &nbsp;<a href="'+f['url']+'">'+f['name']+'</a></td><td class="center" style="width:50px;">'+(f['dir']?'':_s(f['size']))+'</td><td class="center" style="width:110px;">'+f['date']+'</td></tr>';
    }
    tbl.innerHTML=html+'</table>';
}
<?php foreach($dirs as $d)print sprintf("_d('%s','%s','%s');\n",addslashes($d['name']),date($date,$d['date']),addslashes($d['url'])); ?>
<?php foreach($files as $f)print sprintf("_f('%s',%d,'%s','%s',%d);\n",addslashes($f['name']),$f['size'],date($date,$f['date']),addslashes($f['url']),$f['date']);?>

window.onload=function()
{
    idx=_obj('idx'); _head(); _srt('name');
};
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="idx"><!-- do not remove --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Preview:

[image: screenshot file manager]

[gist](https://gist.github.com/NabiKAZ/91f716faa89aab747317fe09db694be8)

Comment: add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` into **head** tag, will make page view size nice for smart devices like mobiles, tablets, etc...

Comment: @a55 Thanks for your suggestion, I added it. ( 4kerim! ;-) )

Comment: @a55 Hi, Thanks for your feedback, New Update: Compatible with PHP 8 and modified to display the added date and time format.

Answer (score 0):

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t . script.php
Script.php:
<?php
    ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");
    $fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $dir = '.'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (!is_file($dir)){
        $handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Cannot open " . $dir);
        header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
        echo("<style>a{color:black;width:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:row;}a:hover{color:black;}</style>");
        echo "<b>Index of " . $dir . ": </b><br/>";
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                if (is_dir($file)) {
                    echo "<a href=\"".$file."/\">".$file."</a><br/>";
                }else{
                    echo "<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br/>";
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

php -S localhost:4443 -t . route.php

route.php :

```
$f=preg_replace('/\/$/','',__DIR__."{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
if(is_dir($f)){
$abf=preg_replace('/\/$/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$fs=glob("$f/*");
foreach($fs as $one){
    $one=str_replace($f.'/','',$one);
    echo "<a href='$abf$one'>$one</a><br/>";
}
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can add the explanation what this code really doing?