# How to configure local PHP to show directory content

Tags: php

I have a local version of Windows php to test my webpage. I run it using php.exe. It has a built-in webserver so pages can be accessed from a browser through localhost:/path.

If I enter an URL pointing to a file it opens that file in browser. I would like to configure it so that it shows the content of a directory if URL points to a directory. E.g. after inserting URL http://localhost:1234/foo/bar/ into the browser I would want to see the files in the bar directory listed in the browser. Similarly how other webservers do it when configured so.
My local PHP returns 404 instead.

Is there any way how to achieve that for this built-in webserver in php.exe? How?

Comment: is there any .htaccess file ? or you are handling requests inside php ?

Comment: Yes, see also the answer. I am using the built-in PHP webserver for dev testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in server is specifically for quick development and debugging as stated in the [command line server doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) and directory listing is one of the features is lacks. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946964/php-built-in-server-any-way-to-configure-it-to-show-files-of-directory#answer-14947054) provides an example for building yours though.